# macOS NetworkingDriverKit - How can I register multiple ethernet interfaces?

Tags: macos, iokit, driverkit

I have tried extending `IOUserNetworkEthernet` and calling `RegisterEthernetInterface()`. This works perfectly for one ethernet interface, though the driver crashes when `RegisterEthernetInterface` is called a second time (doesn't return an error code). I have tried registering with separate queues.

Another approach was extending `IOUserClient` instead, and calling `IOService::Create` to create child IOUserNetworkEthernet instances. Everything about this approach works (the children appear within ioreg). However, once I call `RegisterEthernetInterface` on just one of the children, macOS crashes.

How would I go about creating a dext with multiple ethernet interfaces? Have I been approaching it the right way?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't yet implemented an ethernet dext myself, but based on my experience with using DriverKit for other types of drivers and knowing its design goals, I have an idea what the solution might be.

**First off, let's clarify:** you're implementing either a *virtual* ethernet device, or you're building a driver for hardware that unites *multiple independent ports* in one physical device. In the former case (I'm guessing this is what you're doing based on your `IOUserClient` comment), your driver will be matching `IOUserResources` and you create the ethernet driver instance when you receive the corresponding message from your user space component.

**Now, DriverKit design:** DriverKit is built around a goal of keeping the driver instance for each device in its own separate process. Sort of circling back to the microkernel idea. Specifically, this means that *multiple devices that use the same driver will each create an independent instance of that driver in its own process.* This very likely means that NetworkingDriverKit was never designed to support more than one instance of `IOUserNetworkEthernet`, because they are seen as separate devices. Hence the crashes.

**OK, what do we do about it?** Use DriverKit the way it was intended. Put each virtual ethernet adapter in its own driver instance. This gets a bit tricky. I *think* this should work:

- Your dext has a "control" instance. This is the thing that matches `IOUserResources`. It's a simple `IOService` class which listens for the signal (presumably `IOUserClient`) to create or destroy a virtual ethernet device. When creating a virtual ethernet device, you need that to run in its own driver instance though. (For an actual device with multiple ports, this would match the USB/PCI device nub, manage bus communication with the device, and enumerate the ports.)
- Instead of creating an instance of a `IOUserNetworkEthernet` subclass, create an instance of a "nub" class and attach it to your central control class instance. Call `RegisterService()` in its startup code, so it's considered for IOKit matching.
- Set up a second IOKit matching dictionary in your Info.plist, which matches your new "nub" object. Here, use your `IOUserNetworkEthernet`-derived class to "drive" the nub. Once the virtual ethernet device is ready to use, call `RegisterEthernetInterface()`.

**2 extra things to note:**

1. The virtual device will run in a separate process from the control object, so they can only communicate via DriverKit inter-process calls, i.e. user clients. Hopefully, they don't really need to communicate much though, and the control client can pass all the information required via properties on the nub. If you're implementing support for multi-port hardware, you probably won't be able to avoid this part though.
2. Your user space component (app, daemon) will need to open a new communication channel with the virtual device, so you'll probably need to implement user client support there too.

I'm not sure how you'd go about shutting down an individual virtual ethernet device, you could try calling `Terminate()` on either it or the nub it's matched on and see what happens.

Comment: You're a champion. Works great.
For anyone trying something similar in the future, make sure the IOUserNetworkEthernet matching dictionary is directly under the IOKitPersonalities key. Make sure it has a unique IOUserServerName. Also match the base class of the "nub" you want to connect to, not the class itself with IOProviderClass.

Comment: @JakeStewart, I am working on a similar stuff. Could you please share any sample code on RegisterEthernetInterface() method, start(), stop(), free(). I know about matching dictionary which help to find specific USB device. What I found ifnet_t and struct mbuf are deprecated now. I don't know how to allocate network buffer, copy network buffer. Not finding any sample code or in depth documentation. Appreciate your help

Comment: deprecated documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/interface_nke/interface_nke.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001858-CH231-SW9 . Appreciate any help